# FILTER_VALIDATE_URL not accepting Japanese text included URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-validation

I am using `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` for checking user given URL is valid or not. Unfortunately the function  `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` return false when user input Japanese text included URL. 
But I want to allow Japanese characters included URL. How it is possible? Is there any function for allowing it?

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL validates according to [RFC2396][1]. In particular, see section 2.1


  [1]: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me right, `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` itself cannot be modified to work with Japanese characters, you would be required to create your own implementation.

The source of the function can be viewed here http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#php_filter_validate_url.

Note thought that it is C code (as it is part of the PHP core) and not PHP.